# FTP site not connecting in IE

Tags: windows, ftp, internet-explorer, amazon-web-services, plesk

I just created my new website in the AWS lightsail. The website is hosted using the Plesk package on Windows server 2012 R2. I created one domain with the anonymous ftp access along with some ftp users. I configured the IP to be dedicated. All TCP ports are enabled in firewall. Now my problem is when I try to access the ftp in IE the site is not connecting.

I am able to connect to the site anonymously and with user credentials in all other than IE browsers and FTP client like filezilla. Is there any settings in either IIS or Plesk that blocks the connection of FTP while connecting through IE?

Answer (score 0):

After searching around the web i finally resolved the issue. It was the passive port. In IIS i did not put the passive port range. I thought that when i updated the passive port range in Plesk it will take care of it but it did not and when i updated passive port range in IIS FTP site worked in IE also.

For settings i refered the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470039/how-to-enable-ftp-passive-mode-for-amazon-ec2-server-with-iis)